# Can I separate the lines in textAreaInputt?

Tags: r, shiny

I implemented a textAreaInput. Now I want to create a vector in which each element is one line.

So if a user types in:

```
Hello
There
```

I want this Vector:

```
c(Hello,There)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this `unlist(strsplit(input$inp,"\n"))`

[image]

UI

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Text Area"),


    ###the plot

    mainPanel(
      textAreaInput('inp', label = "Enter your text"),
      textOutput('text_op1'),
      textOutput('text_op2')
    )
  )
)
```

server

```
##server

library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  split_text <- reactive({
    unlist(strsplit(input$inp,"\n"))
  })

  output$text_op1 <- renderText({

    split_text()


  })

  output$text_op2 <- renderText({

    #split_text()
    length(split_text())

  })
})
```

And in case if you want to disply the actual vector like it's -  `paste0("c(",paste0(split_text(),collapse = ","),")")`